# How well does the current DreamWeaver work with complex PHP frameworks?

Tags: frameworks, ide, dreamweaver, php

I've always been intrigued by DreamWeaver, particularly the ability to click on something and edit its CSS right there so I don't have to find it in my huge list of CSS.  However, I use a pretty complex home-made MVC framework for my coding that loads and creates pages through a series of includes, classes, function calls, etc.  Quite a while ago, I tried a little to get Dreamweaver to even load a page but gave up pretty quickly.  It wouldn't even display a single thing.  I didn't try anything special though to get it to work like messing in the settings though.

I was wondering if DreamWeaver can handle something like this at this point and if so, what version would I need and how can I find out how to do it?  If not, does anyone know of a good visual IDE where I can edit CSS just by clicking on something that would also support a complex PHP MVC framework page loading process?

Comment: Firefox allows you to right click > inspect element > edit rules live > open style sheet & save. And doesn't cost £500 :)

Comment: Seriously though, I use [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com) myself, it has good code features, highlighting, code completion etc. While it doesn't have a live css editor I can easily search my stylesheets and find the rule I'm after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to know how to develop a Dreamweaver extensions. The following resource, official Adobe website, offers a manual to do that:

http://www.adobe.com/support/dreamweaver/extend.html#dw8